# Kotlin - Generic type safe, wrong warning? java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I'm fetching response from some *API*, after getting the response I converting it to List of my required `Object` e.g:

```
fun <T> getAsList(input: String): ArrayList<T> {
    val objType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}.type
    val result = Gson().fromJson(input, objType) as ArrayList<T>
    println(result[0]) // <-- no warning here !! It's work
    println("result: " + result.toString()) // Also it's work here
    return result
}
```

Then I pass this list to somewhere e.g:

```
updateFromDownload(getAsList<T>(resultValue))
```

And by override this method I can get the result, e.g:

```
override fun updateFromDownload(result: List<Response>?) {

                val listTest = ArrayList<Response>()
                listTest.add(result!![0]) // <-- This work
                println(listTest)


                println("resss:"  + result[0]) // <-- This not work !!!
                for (response in result){
                    // The loop crash too, not work
                }
```

As demonstrated above, adding to `listTest` work fine, but If I tried to get the element individually like I did inside `getAsList()` It's crash due to:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to ......Response

Can I access the `result` directly without fill it to new list?

Edit- Whole cycle for code:

```
class ConnectToURL<T>(callback: DownloadCallback<T>) : AsyncTask<String, Int, ConnectToURL.Result>() {

private var mCallback: DownloadCallback<T>? = null

init {
    setCallback(callback)
}

override fun onPostExecute(result: Result?) {
    mCallback?.apply {
        result?.mException?.also { exception ->
            //val gson = Gson().fromJson(result.mResultValue!!, type)
            //updateFromDownload(gson)
            return
        }
        result?.mResultValue?.also { resultValue ->
            updateFromDownload(getAsList<T>(resultValue))
            return
        }
        finishDownloading()
        }
    }

}
```

And I Invoke `ConnectToURL` from:

```
 class BuilderClass<T> private constructor(
    callback: DownloadCallback<T>,
    private val url: String
) {

    init {
        ConnectToURL(callback).execute(url)
    }

    /// some code . . .. .

        fun build() = BuilderClass(callback, url)
    }
}
```

Then I override the `updateFromDownload` function as it's part from `DownloadCallback`

Answer (score 0):

The generic type `T` is erased at compile time, so the type information is not present at runtime.

```
object : TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}.type
```

Thats the reason Gson does not convert to the `Response` class.
You could use `inline` plus `reified` to avoid type erasure.

```
inline fun <reified T> getAsList(input: String): ArrayList<T>
```

Comment: There is a compile error arise here -> `updateFromDownload(getAsList<T>(resultValue)`  and it's because I Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. I need to use class instead.

Comment: It is the same problem. At the place where you invoke `getAsList` the type parameter `T` is not reified. You need to specify `inline` and `reified` for this function as well. Be aware that all the code of the functions are copied to the invocation place.

Comment: Also, **The generic type T is erased at compile time, so the type information is not present at runtime.** Can I ask how it's legal to put it in new list like I did ? `val listTest = ArrayList<Response>()
                listTest.add(result!![0])`

Comment: `inline` is only possible for generic function types and not for generic class types. You need to show the whole code to give you a good advice. It is not feasible to declare all as inline. Normally you define the top function as inline reified and convert the generic type parameter to a `Class`-object. This object is then used as a normal parameter for the other functions.